# How to run a Ruby script in my ruby on rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby script (example.rb) and I want to run it when a user click on a button on my Ruby on Rails website! What are the steps in order to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share with us what your script must do?

Comment: The script is long!!! but at the end it will launch an EC2 instance! Dost this much enough or you need more info?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have an action that will be called upon clicking the button. Then in the action you can use %x to call your script. For example:

```
def my_action
  result = %x(ruby example.rb)
end
```

If you want to run the script in the context of the rails application, you will want to use rails runner.

```
def my_action
  result = %x(bin/rails runner example.rb)
end
```

You can find more useful info about executing shell commands in ruby [here](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands).

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but still comes up on the first page of a google search so here is what I use.

The [`rails runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) command will execute the file in the context of your rails app.

```
rails runner [path to file].rb
```

**Edit:**  After using this a few times, I found that you can add `RAILS_ENV=production` to the beginning of the command to specify the environment to run the script in.